# keras layer with constrained weights raises error during the init of the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am training an actor-critic model that has a constrained layer in the actor network. The constraint forces the weights to be diagonal. Below is a min reproducible example

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Conv1D, Concatenate, BatchNormalization, Reshape
from tensorflow.keras.constraints import Constraint
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import set_session
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K


import numpy as np
import random
from collections import deque

tf.disable_v2_behavior() 

# For more repetitive results
np.random.seed(1)
random.seed(1)

class DiagonalWeight(Constraint):
    """Constrains the weights to be diagonal.
    """
    def __call__(self, w):
        N = K.int_shape(w)[-1]
        m = K.eye(N)
        return w*m

state_shape = (10,3)
class AC():
    def __init__(self, sess, LRA, LRC):
        self.sess = sess     #session
        
        self.LRA = LRA                                   #learning rate for actor
        self.LRC = LRC                                   #learning rate for critic
        
        self.graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        set_session(self.sess)

        # training actor and target actor 
        self.actor, self.input_actor = self.create_actor()
        plot_model(self.actor, to_file='Ac_architecture.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
        self.target_actor, _ = self.create_actor()
        ###initialize the weights of the target with the weights of training actor
        self.target_actor.set_weights(self.actor.get_weights())

        #training critic and target critic
        self.critic, self.critic_state_input, self.critic_action_input = self.create_critic()
        self.target_critic, _, _  = self.create_critic()
        plot_model(self.critic, to_file='Cr_architecture.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
        ###initialize the weights of the target with the weights of training critic
        self.target_critic.set_weights(self.critic.get_weights())


        ######################## Actor/Critic Grads ########################################################
        self.actor_critic_grad = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, state_shape[0], state_shape[0]+2])   
        actor_weights = self.actor.trainable_weights
        self.actor_grads = tf.gradients(self.actor.output, actor_weights, -self.actor_critic_grad) 
        grads = zip(self.actor_grads, actor_weights)
        self.optimize = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.LRA).apply_gradients(grads) 
        self.critic_grads = tf.gradients(self.critic.output, self.critic_action_input)

        # Initialize for later gradient calculations
        self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        #######################################################################################################################

    def create_actor(self):
        actor_input = Input(shape=state_shape, name='state_input')     
        h3 = Conv1D(128, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', name='h3')(actor_input)
        h3 = BatchNormalization(name='h3_BN')(h3)

        matrix = Conv1D(state_shape[0], 3, padding='same', activation='relu', name='matrix')(h3)
        vect0= Conv1D(1, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', name='vect0')(h3)
        vect0_resh = Reshape((1, state_shape[0]))(vect0)
        vect1 = Dense(state_shape[0], activation='relu', name='vect1',\
                              use_bias=False, kernel_constraint=DiagonalWeight())(vect0_resh) #, kernel_constraint=DiagonalWeight()
        vect1 = Reshape((state_shape[0],1))(vect1)
        actor_output = Concatenate(axis=-1)([vect0, vect1, matrix]) 

        model = Model(actor_input, actor_output)  
        adam  = Adam(lr=self.LRA)
        model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=adam)
        return model, actor_input

    def create_critic(self):
        state_input = Input(shape=state_shape, name='state_input')     
        action_input = Input(shape=(state_shape[0],state_shape[0]+2), name='action_input')                                           
        critic_input = Concatenate(axis=-1)([state_input, action_input]) 
        h3 = Conv1D(128, 3, padding='same', name='h3')(critic_input)
        h3 = BatchNormalization(name='h3_BN')(h3)

        Q = Conv1D(state_shape[0]+2, 3, padding='same', name='Q')(h3)

        model = Model([state_input, action_input], Q)
        adam  = Adam(lr=self.LRC)
        model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=adam)
        return model, state_input, action_input


sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
K.set_session(sess)
agent = AC(sess, 0.01, 0.001)
```

When I romove the kernel constraint from the dense layer, everything works fine, but when I add it, I get one of the following three errors:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_19' with dtype float and shape [?,10,12]
         [[node Placeholder_19 (defined at AC.py:59) ]]
```

or

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'state_input' with dtype float and shape [?,10,3]
         [[node state_input (defined at AC.py:73) ]]
```

or

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable beta1_power from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/beta1_power/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
         [[node Adam/update_vect1/kernel/ResourceApplyAdam/ReadVariableOp (defined at AC.py:64) ]]
```

The kernel in the dense layer is a square matrix, so applying the diagonal constraint should pose no problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in the solution:
In `class DiagonalWeight`, I changed the line `m = K.eye(N)` with `m = tf.eye(N)`

I don't know exactly how does this worked, but I gess it is something related to the session. Tensorflow needs to store the operation for future use in the training.